# Invalid update: invalid number of sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'

but i insert 1 and deleted one based on data source what i missed

```
    self.states?.append(sortedStates) //Update state  property
    if (self.states?.count)! > 3 {
        self.states?.removeFirst()
    }
  self.newsFeedTableView.beginUpdates()
  self.newsFeedTableView.insertSections([(self.states?.count)! - 1], with: .none)
  if (self.states?.count)! > 3 {           
      let statesForoldestStateTime = self.states?.first
      self.newestStateTime = statesForoldestStateTime?.first?.createdAt
      let indexpostion = (self.states?.count)! - 3
     self.newsFeedTableView.deleteSections([indexpostion], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    }
  self.newsFeedTableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Only update when the conditions are met.

Comment: Not related but consider to consolidate your incredible amount of question marks.  For example why is `states` optional at all?

Comment: @vadian data load from web that is the reason declared   `var states : [[State]]?`

Comment: In most cases it's more suitable to declare collection types as an empty non-optional type `var states = [[State]]()` especially for data source arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all. When `if (self.states?.count)! > 3`  is false. The only section would be inserted and not deleted.
You should update your data source accordingly. The number of sections method must return `someArray.count`. When you insert some section, make sure to update that some array, and when you delete some section, delete the element from some array. That will resolve the issue.